# Solution Veriification: Describe the quotient Topology on Y induced by f

Tags: general-topology

Let Y={1,2,3} and define f:$\mathbb{R} \to Y$ by f(x)=1 if x<0 , f(x)= 2 if x=0 and f(x) =3 if x>0 . Describe the quotient topology on Y induced by f.

I think the  topology will be this set ={{1},{3},{13},$\phi$}.

Am I right?

If I am wrong then kindly tell the right topology and why it is so.

Thanks!

Comment: Your answer is almost correct, you only forgot $Y$ itself. The whole space is always an element of a topology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The open sets in the quotient are exactly those whose preimages are open.

If $Y$ is finite, then you can find the topology by simply checking the preimages of all the subsets of $Y$.

The subsets of $Y$ which you have not included are $\{2\}, \{1,2\}, \{2,3\}, \{1,2,3\}$. One of them has open preimage.